# Proof the quotient and remainder exists in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, prove that there exists an integer $q$ called 
the quotient and an integer $r$ called the remainder such that $a = q b + r$ and
$0 \leq r < b$.

I've seen proofs for this problem and I have been given a solution using induction but I've half thought of a proof that seems much simpler but I'm not sure if it is correct.

There are 3 cases, case 1 and 2 are simple so I'll only half prove case 3.

Case 1: $a=b$

Case 2: $a < b$

Case 3: $b<a$. Then there exists an integer $q=gcd(a,b)$. This step worries me since we use the above theorem to calculate the $gcd$ but I don't think the above theorem says anything about its existence. So even without the theorem above we can be sure of its existence. Therefore we can let $r=a-gcd(a,b)b$. So if I could prove $0\leq r < b$ would the proof be correct?

Comment: Actually, this is not the right value of $q$. Consider $a=40$ and $b=2$. Then $\gcd(a,b)=2$, but $36=40-4$ is neither zero nor one.

Comment: The other problem with using the $\gcd(a,b)$ value is that it may not be big enough.  Consider $a=9, b=2$.

Comment: I should have spotted that, thanks for pointing it out. What if a replaced $gcd$ with $floor(\frac{a}{b})$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove the statement by induction on $a$.

The case $a=0$ is easy. Suppose the statement holds for $a$ and try it for $a+1$. By inductive hypothesis
$$
a=bq+r
$$
with $0\le r<b$. Then $a+1=bq+(r+1)$, but $r+1$ might fail to be less than $b$: when?

Answer (score -1):

Alternately, given $a,b > 0$, you can consider the set $S = \{a - bq : q \in \mathbb{Z}, a - bq \geq 0\}$. This set is nonempty, and thus has a least element by the Well-Ordering Principle. Call this least element $r$.

It is now very easy to prove that $r$ satisfies the desired inequality (otherwise, it wouldn't be the least element in $S$) and this gives you your unique $q,r$. $\diamondsuit$